# How can I remote access into a WinCE client computer from a Windows 2000 system?

Tags: server, client, windows-ce, remote-access, windows-2000

I am currently running a server with Windows 2000 and running client computers off the same switch/network which are running Windows CE. I was wondering if there was a way for me to remote access into my Windows CE clients from my Windows 2000 server? Please let me know your thoughts, I greatly appreciate any constructive input.

-Manny

Edit
It doesn't necessarily need to be remote access. If there is a way for me to detect the client, maybe a DHCP change, and then allowing me to run script from the server into the client computer, that would work too! Thank you in advance once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Window CE does not have RDP host for other systems to connect but you can use application like CERDisp which connect to your Windows CE / Windows Mobile terminal over active sync and display its screens in a window. You can also use the mouse and keyboard on the desktop to remote control the device the same as if you were using the popup PDA keyboard and the stylus.

We have used it long time back. For some information you can look at http://nicolasbesson.blogspot.in/2007/12/enable-remote-display-application.html
You can download this application from http://www.naurtech.com/wiki/wiki.php?n=Main.ToolsCERDisp

There are additional application like Remote Display that allows to operate the target device's Win CE desktop from a Windows PC. It requires a USB ActiveSync or Ethernet connection. For information you can review at http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/remote-display

Comment: You're amazing, thank you so much! I will give these a try and will keep you updated. Hope you have a good rest of your day!